# Populating a form using a url - multiple input types

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post, get

Hi I'm trying to create a form that is pre-populated partially by form on the page before. This information is then posted to this new page which is then populated into the form on that page ready to be submitted to a database.

I'm not a developer so I'm a little out of my depth here but this is what I've got so far..

```
<?php
    $amount = $_GET['text-386'];
    $covermultiple = $_GET['radio-30'];
    $coverdobd = $_GET['d-o-b-d'];
    $coverdobm = $_GET['d-o-b-m'];
    $coverdoby = $_GET['d-o-b-y'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('text-386').value = "<?=$amount ?>";
    document.getElementByName('radio-30').checked = "checked";
    document.getElementById('d-o-b-d').value = "<?=$coverdobd ?>";
    document.getElementById('d-o-b-m').value = "<?=$coverdobm ?>";
    document.getElementById('d-o-b-y').value = "<?=$coverdoby ?>";
</script>
```

I'm getting the values out of the URL ok and can echo these out on the page fine, I've even managed to get text-386 appearing in the right place.. so thats one down! The problem is the other elements are a radio button with two options (radio-30) and a 3 select boxes with the days, months and year of a persons d-o-b. These two bits are populating.

So in a nutshell..

How can I use javascript (if that is the right way) alongside php to populate the radio and select tags on this form using information in the url? In a preferably straight forward way as possible?

The url if it helps is..

http://localhost/datacapture/form-page/radio-30=Just+for+me&text-386=%C2%A340%2C000&d-o-b-d=11&d-o-b-m=05&d-o-b-y=1977

Thats obviously on the local build I'm using so that URL wouldn't work for you. I can see when googling lots of help posting information using radio/select etc but I want the opposite, how do you populate these from a url?

Any help would be a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an if statement.

```
if( $covermultiple == "Just for me" ) {
  // Echo the field here
  echo "<input type='radio' name='radio-30' value='Just for me' checked />";
}

else {
  // Check for the next case
}
```

Put this block right where you want the radio buttons to be.

I think something like that will work fine. I don't think you really need javascript in this case unless you really want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% I have an answer, but I cant find comment anywhere so I will joust post here.

1. You cant access PHP variables from Javascript. PHP is running on the server, and Javascript is inside users browser.
2. Javascript cant get $_GET and $_POST variables like PHP.

Now what you can do is this, with JavaScript you can get document.location string that holds your current URL. And you can brake that URL into parts. To do that use this function:

```
<script>

var $_GET = {};

document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
    function decode(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
    }

    $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});

alert($_GET['someVar']); // This will alert content of someVar
```

Now you can use $_GET['vars'] to get your URL vars.

And then you dont use PHP to echo variable content, you joust prepare your URL so it holds variables you want to insert into your form.

So you do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('text-386').value = $_GET['urlVar'];
    document.getElementByName('radio-30').checked = "checked";
    document.getElementById('d-o-b-d').value = $_GET['urlVar'];
    document.getElementById('d-o-b-m').value = $_GET['urlVar'];
    document.getElementById('d-o-b-y').value = $_GET['urlVar'];
</script>
```

So as you can see, JavaScript takes variables from URL, using function $_GET you wrote and it dosent needs PHP. And you can use PHP to generate URLs you need, so they contain variables you can get using $_GET javascript function.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hey,thanks I get the principle but when I've added this to my code it doesn't seem to be materialising. I can alert the values out but this javascript doesn't seem to be materialising. Sorry if I'm missing something really obvious.